Programatically get name of dataclass property
Let's say I have a dataclass like this:
@dataclass(init=True)
class TestDataclass:
    property1: str

I want to fetch the name of this property like TestDataclass.property1.__name__, however this throws an AttributeError, saying that the class/type does not have this attribute.
The reason why I want this is because I use dependency injection based on the attribute names and I don't want to use hardcoded strings in case someone decides to change them in the future.
Here's the difference:
di["property1"] = "THIS IS BAD"
di[TestDataclass.property1.__name__] = "I wish this worked"


You can ask for the fields of a dataclass, and a Field has a name, but then you'd have to find the right one in the tuple using the string. That might work for your purposes, but it's not entirely clear what they are.

How would you expect to reference that property if someone changed its name?

when you say you are using dependency injection, do you mean you are using some dependency injection framework?

how would di[TestDataclass.property1.__name__] help you if it worked? You'd still have property1 hard-coded in there. I think at end of the day any DI will need the objects being injected to conform to a common interface.

@Anentropic Because a static code analyzer can see that this field name has changed and throw an error. Usually you wouldn't even reach this step because most IDEs have a function to rename all references to something.

@yut23 See my answer to Anentropic
